# Is XeTeX a complete rewrite of LaTeX/TeX?

Tags: xetex

I have been looking into XeTeX for type-setting Unicode Text. I looked into the source code of it. XeTeX source distribution comes with Web2C. Is XeTeX a complete rewrite of TeX? If not, how did it accomplish the goal of adding the support for Unicode?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, XeTeX was not created by completely rewriting TeX. Rather, it was created by starting from e-TeX and making changes using a `.ch` file (WEB change file). The change file tackles two big areas: extending the internals of (e-)TeX for Unicode, and extending font loading. The [current TeX Live XeTeX source](http://ftp.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/xetexdir/) features both this `.ch` file and an equivalent `.web` file.

Comment: I'm not sure quite how everything fits together for the file reading stuff: I have enough trouble even reading WEB files, let alone linking together with other stuff :-)

Comment: Actually in SVN the main change file is already merged so `xetex.web` is now the canonical source (this wasn’t the case few weeks ago, we didn’t even have a `xetex.web` files it was created at build time), the remaining change file is for some minor stuff.

Answer (score 29):

XeTeX is not a complete rewriting of TeX. Here are some of the main changes.

1. **The input stage.** XeTeX by default reads Unicode files (UTF-8, for instance), although it's capable of interpreting also differently encoded files (for backwards compatibility). Multibyte characters are reduced to a single internal character upon reading, so they are considered as a unique entity when tokenization is performed; you can have command names in cyrillic, if you want, but I wouldn't recommend this practice.
2. **The font management.** The font management part has been completely reworked by *adding* support for OpenType and TrueType fonts, delegating some parts to the `fontconfig` library (and to the Apple font library in case XeTeX is run on Mac OS X).
3. **The math font set up.** XeTeX introduces new primitives for extending the `\mathcode` and `\mathchardef` features in TeX and allowing for specifying characters in the whole Unicode set and in 256 math families (instead of TeX's 16).
4. **"Post-processing" features (A).** XeTeX links to the `teckit` library so it can apply a `.map` file that allows for transforming characters in already formed token lists before they are processed in the "stomach" for typesetting. This is how `Ligatures=TeX` works, attaching to the font a `map` directive that transforms the usual combinations into a single character, for instance `---` into `—`.
5. **"Post-processing" features (B).** Characters can be assigned to an "interchar token class" and it's possible to specify tokens to be added when there is a transition from a class to another. The packages `polyglossia`, `xeCJK` and `ucharclasses` exploit this feature.

The process of typesetting, instead, is essentially the same as TeX's. However some changes have been made also in the hyphenation stage that *may* give slightly different results if the same file is compiled with `pdftex` or `xetex`.

Comment: So font management is partly delegated to OS-specific libraries (`fontconfig` vs. Apple font library). Does this imply any danger that the typesetting result may be different on MacOS than on other systems? (I remember horrible experiences with OpenOffice Impress on Linux, Windows and MacOS in this respect, which triggered my conversion to LaTeX `beamer`)

Comment: @Daniel See [this recent thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94297/are-xetex-and-luatex-platform-dependent) about the problem

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how I could miss it.

Answer (score 10):

`XeTeX` is a full utf8 Version of `TeX` and available with all TeX distributions. The only difference is the font handling, because `XeTeX` can handle OpenType as well as TrueType fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontface\Chinese{KaiTi_GB2312}% simkai.ttf

\begin{document}
Это мой первый многоязычный доклад.

This is my first multilingual report.

\Chinese
这是我的第一个多语种的报告。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference at the source code level?

Comment: The font handling ...

Comment: So it uses exactly the TeX's expansion, glue-handling and breaking-handling algorithms?

Comment: @tohecz: as far as OpenType features are not involved you'll get the same output

Comment: @Herbert your several rollbacks all break formatting… let the Chinese text be inside the block quote.

Comment: @F'x: no in some web browsers you can't see the chinese characters when they are in the code part, eg in my opera

Comment: @Herbert I have Opera too and it works fine… I think you're merely missing a CJK monospaced font

Comment: @F'x: hm, I have hundrets of fonts installed. Which one do you have for monospaced chinese characters?

Comment: @Herbert in that particular case, both Opera and Safari on Mac OS Mountain Lion use [ＭＳ 明朝](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_明朝) (and it works)

Comment: @F'x: didn't work for me, also no change with Code2000. However, I did a rollback to the edited version of Konrad. If you can see it then it will be fine ...

Comment: @Herbert yes, works fine with me…